# How to check if a movie is playing? (if possible)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a way to check whether a movie is currently playing by querying the `MPMoviePlayerController` (not by registering callbacks)? I'm looking for something similar to `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` in android. I looked over the documentation and didn't find a way, though I might missed something...

Currently I am registering to callbacks, but I want to know if there's such a method before maintaining the state by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `playbackState`?  According to Apple's docs it should return the information you need:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW40

It returns one of the following states:

```
enum {
   MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward
};
typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not used to access properties this way :)